# Ubuntu 20.04 - Save wired network with static IP

Tags: ubuntu, ip, wired-networking

I've set up a new wired connection with a static IP in order to connect to the internet at my university. We're provided with a static IP, netmask, gateway, and 2 DNS (IPv4) to connect. I've configured it using the Network tab in the GUI Settings.

However, I'm often not here and I connect to another network where I'll need dynamic IP to be enabled (and therefore switch off "Manual" in the IPv4 tab, deleting all information I typed in)

Is there a simple way to save my network settings and re-activate them when I dock?

I've taken a look at nmcli, but it wasn't obvious how to proceed. I'd be satisfied by some sort of command-line script that I can set up as well.

Comment: Might this help you to create appropriate scripts? [https://www.tecmint.com/nmcli-configure-network-connection/](https://www.tecmint.com/nmcli-configure-network-connection/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "Network" tab, you should see a "+" button next to the "Wired" header; this allows you to create an additional network profile with its own settings.

You can do the same using `nmcli con add`:

```
nmcli con add type ether con-name "University LAN"
```

Afterwards, you can associate the profiles with MAC addresses if the dock has a different one.